# Pass multiple variable with putExtra

Tags: android, variables, android-activity

I have some variables that I want to pass to my next activity, but I can't figure a way to do that.

My variables are:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
String propId = jsonObj.getString("id");
Log.i("Value id", propId);
String propCity = jsonObj.getString("city");
Log.i("Value city", propCity);
String propPlace = jsonObj.getString("place");
Log.i("Value place", propPlace);
String propStation = jsonObj.getString("station");
Log.i("Value station", propStation);
```

and the code I used to get them is:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("id", propId);
extras.putString("city", propCity);
extras.putString("place", propPlace);
extras.putString("station", propStation);
```

Can anyone help me with this please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you posted is to write them to the Bundle, after you write in the Bundle use `.putExtras()` to put your bundle in your `Intent`.

```
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("id", propId);
extras.putString("city", propCity);
extras.putString("place", propPlace);
extras.putString("station", propStation);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

To read it in your activity use [`getExtras()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29) to get the [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) you passed to it and then use [`getString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)/`getXXX`.

Anyway, you can avoid the creation of the `Bundle` and use directly the set methods of `Intent` which works in the same way.

So it would be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
intent.putExtra("id", propId);
intent.putExtra("city", propCity);
intent.putExtra("place", propPlace);
intent.putExtra("station", propStation);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I did it, but the problem is that Eclipse tells me that propId, propCity, propPlace and propStation can't be resolved to variables.

Comment: You should add more code, this problem could be caused by the fact you read there prop in a for and then try to read it out the for

Comment: That's it, I set them in a for, and my putExtra is out of the for.

Comment: propId/etc. lives only inside the for or you declare them out of the for or you put the putExtras code in the for

Comment: Okay, I have no more errors on the first activity. Now, I need to assign my values to differents TextView or something like that, can you give me an hint ?

Comment: I have this code: 

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String dateDepl = extras.getString("id");
    String cityDepl = extras.getString("city");
    String placeDepl = extras.getString("place");
    String stationDepl = extras.getString("station");

Comment: Yes, then to print it to a TextView just do textView.setText(dateDepl); remember in your variables you will have what you passed (and check if getExtras is not null too!)

Comment: How can I assign it by the id of the textView ? For example, with tvDate which will receive dateDepl ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment? The textview gets the id by findViewById... open a new question if you got a new question you will get more answers

Comment: I finished it, but I got a problem. Since the extras.putString are in the for, they always take the value of the lasts propId, propCity, etc... But I want it to take the values of the item I click on. Do you got any hints for it please ?

Comment: Yes, you should choose what you want to do... send all info or the last one? the first? what?

Comment: I want to send the info for the item I click on

Comment: then you need to pass jsonArray.getJSONObject(itemClicked) without code i'm unable to help you more. But anyway, accept this answer and post a new question with the code (as i said, you will get more answer and a more clear question).

Answer (score 2):

Use [Parcelables](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) instead. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181792/760893) you have an example.

Parcelable is the way Android uses to communicate between activites. In order to use it, you must create a class that implements Parcelable:

```
import android.

public class MyClass implements Parcelable
{
     private string userName;
     private int userAge;

     public void SetUserName(string name) { userName = name; }
     public string GetUserName() { return userName; }

     public void SetUserAge(int age) { userAge = age; }
     public int GetUserAge() { return age; }

    // Some inner stuff
}
```

This class needs to implement the `WriteToParcel` method, which writes into a Parcel all the needed info:

```
    @Override 
    public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
         dest.writeString(userName);
         dest.writeInt(userAge);
         // Since here you wrote into dest Parcel your string and int
     }
```

In order to be able to read from that Parcel, you need to do the following:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<ExtractionConfig> CREATOR = new Creator<ExtractionConfig>()         {
{
    @Override
    public MyClass [] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyClass [size];
    }

    @Override
    public MyClass createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        MyClass toReturn = new MyClass ();
        toReturn.setUserName(source.readString());
        toReturn.setUserAge(source.readInt());
        return toReturn;
    }
};
```

**IMPORTANT: the writeToParcel order MUST BE THE SAME than the createFromParcel order!!**

**How to pass Parcel between activities:**

When you launch an activity from another one, you call an `Intent`. You can put extra information in it by creating an object of the Parcelable class and fill it:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
myclass.setUserName("first user");
myclass.setUserAge(20);
```

And then put that extra information into your Intent:

**In your main activity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityToBeCalled.class);
intent.putExtra(myclass, "extraclass"); // look at this string, this one will be your identifier to receive the extra information
startActivity(intent);
```

To read information from the intent in the called class:

**In your second activity:**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
MyClass myReceivedClass = intent.getParcelableExtra("extraclass"); // here you use your string identifier defined in putExtra(...);
```

And now, in `myReceivedClass` you should have all your `MyClass` information.

Comment: The parameters of intent.putExtra() are String, Parcelable, not the other way around

Answer (score 1):

You doesn't need to use `Bundle`. You can use `putExtra()` of `Intent` class to pass data to next `Activity` as follows...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);

intent.putExtra("id", propId);
intent.putExtra("city", propCity);
intent.putExtra("place", propPlace);
intent.putExtra("place", propPlace);

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use intents.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,target_activity.class);  
intent.putExtra("name",bundle);  

startActivity(intent);
```

For small and typical data its good enough.For sending objects,use parcelable.

Answer (score 0):

No idea how it was handled earlier, but nowadays you can use `intent.putExtra("extra id", obj)` where obj is any Serializable implementing object. Using `intent.getSerializableExtra("extra id")` you gain an object you can cast to your initially used class.